# How to set Title in center of navigation bar Xamarin.forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

How to set Title into center of Navigation Bar.
Can we set without custom render.
I have used

```
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Toolbar Title" android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />
```

But Its not working

Comment: What have you tried so far? I entered your question into Google and found multiple approaches

Comment: Yes I have search on google but only Custom render are available and On Android I have used

Comment: -
     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Toolbar Title"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />  But Its not working

Comment: Don't add relevant information to the comment section, put it in the question

Answer (score 3):

Here's one hackish way with the new NavigationPage.TitleView - Android seems to reserve a portion of the title view for the back button by default, so you can just set a margin that offsets the left hand reserved area:

```
<ContentPage>
    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="More Text" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Margin="0, 0, 75, 0" />
        </StackLayout>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
        ...
```